# Why isn't the While loop printing?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 0;

int main()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    }

    while(i < 5)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside while Loop" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because value of "I" has been updated to 5 due to for loop.

Comment: This is the point in your life where you learn to not reuse loop variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the above for loop the value of `i` is already incremented to 5 because

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    /* at the end of for loop i=5 */
}
```

now your `i` value is 5 and the condition fails. Try resetting the value of `i`, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You increment i in the first for loop, but never reset it. So when it exits the for loop, i is still 5, so the while loop will never execute it. Set i equal to zero before the while loop, and the while loop will run. If you do this, the loop will run forever, unless you update i inside the loop

Comment: I knew it was a super newbie question! Thank you so much for the reply. I actually posted this because I see lots of new people not asking questions because of the dislikes they received because of the question. I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

When the for loop stops executing, i becomes 5 and hence does not meet the condition for while loop. Set I back to 0 after the for loop.

```
i=0;
while(i<5)
 ..// your code here
 ..
```